# Volume of a neighborhood of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

Suppose we take the set of all $n\times n$ real matrices with entries in $[0,1]$ in Euclidean space.  Let $N_\epsilon$ be the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the set of all singular matrices in this space, i.e. $N_\epsilon = \cup_{A:\det(A)=0} B_\epsilon(A)$.

Is there a simple way to compute or upper-bound the volume of $N_\epsilon$ in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: What is the norm with respect to which you take $B_{\varepsilon}$?

Comment: Let's say the trace inner product, but really I'm looking more for how one might answer this type of question.

Comment: Isn't the volume simply infinite? There are infinitely many singular matrices of pairwise distance $\epsilon$, each one having a neighborhood with a volume of an $(n\times n)$-dimensional ball of radius $\epsilon$ (I assume this is how volume is defined in your case).

Comment: @M.Winter: The OP is restricting to matrices with entries in $[0,1]$.

Comment: The set of singular matrices defines an hypersurface, the volume goes to zero linearly with epsilon

Comment: This is a good point, I suppose I could get away with integrating the determinant to find the area of the hypersurface itself.  Thanks!

Comment: Right, I wouldn't know how to compute the value of the area, but yes, the volume is (epsilon)x(area) + higher order in epsilon